# spring external properties file; file not found exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I am trying to read from an external properties file with the following code below. I am pretty sure I have the path set up correctly but I am still getting the file not found error. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
public class Timer {

     @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext ctx;

     @Autowired
        private SpringMailSender springMailSender;

    @Scheduled(cron="${timer.time}") //this is the line that is having trouble
    public void timer()
    {
        System.out.println("timer() in Timer Class has been stepped into");
        try {
            springMailSender.sendMail();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Method executed on every 2nd Monday of each month. Current time is :: "+ new Date());
    }

}
```

And here is how I have my config file set up for it...

```
<!--  Property Placeholder -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:properties/system.properties</value>
                    <value>file:${external.property.directory}propfilename</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

<!-- messageSource -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>file:${external.property.directory}propfilename</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

With my external file path set up like this in the properties file within the web app.

```
#directory on the server where property files will be stored
external.property.directory=C\:\\propfoldername\\
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${external.property.directory}propfilename (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I left out some code you might need to see.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder in `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` config (spring needs `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to handle `${xxx}` vars)

Comment: you are attempting to use property before configuring it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do wont work because ${external.property.directory} does not get resolved.
You could achieve the same result however using an environment variable in case you need both properties files (take note that any properties in the second one will override the same properties from the first one)

Comment: thanks. I just put the external property line inside my internal properties file instead and that fixed it.